# Why does 两次 change position in 我们每周两次用中文聊十分钟好吗 vs. 我们每周用中文聊天两次好吗？

Tags: translation, word-order

I want to say:

> Shall we chat in Chinese for ten minutes twice a week?

Translator program gives the following output:

> 我们每周**两次**用中文聊十分钟好吗？

When I remove the duration from the sentence, the position of frequency measure word (两次） changes:

> Shall we chat in Chinese twice a week?
> Translation: 我们每周用中文聊天**两次**好吗？

Can someone please explain me why the position changes?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is due to the change in "object" of the sentences.

Shall we chat in Chinese **twice** a week?

- 我们每周用中文 聊 "**两次**" 好吗？- Here, the object "两次" quantifies the action "聊" in a clear manner.

Now, let's translate the sentence "Shall we chat in Chinese "for ten minutes" twice a week?" with the same grammar pattern as the above:

- 我们每周用中文 聊 "**两次十分钟**" 好吗？- The object of this sentence is obviously unclear that renders the sentence unacceptable without modification.

One way to modify the sentence is:

- 我们每周用中文 聊 "**两次**", 每次十分钟, 好吗？- Now the sentence is clear and acceptable, but the added word "每次(each time)" was not part of the original sentence.

The other feasible modification is:

- 我们每周两次用中文 聊 "**十分钟**" 好吗？- Now the sentence is clear, acceptable, without alter the original words, and matches the reult from the translation program.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

我们可以每周用中文聊二次天，每次十分钟吗？

Think separation! You don't have to keep 聊天 together!

Comment: Use 两次 instead of 二次。